# Tests fail with "Class 'Browser" could not be found

Tags: php, phpunit, autoload

I have a test folder structure like:

```
.
├── test
│    └── e2e
│        ├── pages
│        │   └── LoginPage.php
│        └── webdriver
│            └── Browser.php
└── vendor
```

When I run

```
$ vendor\bin\phpunit --bootstrap vendor/autoload.php test\e2e\HomePage.php
```

the test fails with

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PHPUnit\Runner\Exception: Class 'Browser' could not be found in 'C:\Users\rburton\code\MyAgsourceAPI\test\e2e\HomePage.php'. in C:\Users\rburton\code\MyAgsourceAPI\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\StandardTestSuiteLoader.php on line 101

PHPUnit\Runner\Exception: Class 'Browser' could not be found in 'C:\Users\rburton\code\MyAgsourceAPI\test\e2e\HomePage.php'. in C:\Users\rburton\code\MyAgsourceAPI\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\StandardTestSuiteLoader.php on line 101

Call Stack:
    0.1973     357496   1. {main}() C:\Users\rburton\code\MyAgsourceAPI\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:0
    0.2024     746904   2. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main(???) C:\Users\rburton\code\MyAgsourceAPI\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:53
    0.2024     750064   3. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run(array(4), true) C:\Users\rburton\code\MyAgsourceAPI\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:141
    0.2077    1007320   4. PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner->getTest(string(17), string(57), array(2)) C:\Users\rburton\code\MyAgsourceAPI\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:162
    0.2078    1007320   5. PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner->loadSuiteClass(string(17), string(57)) C:\Users\rburton\code\MyAgsourceAPI\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:73
    0.2084    1026680   6. PHPUnit\Runner\StandardTestSuiteLoader->load(string(7), string(57)) C:\Users\rburton\code\MyAgsourceAPI\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:130
```

The only place that I am instantiating the `Browser` class is in the setup for the `HomePage` test class:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    $this->browserDriver = new Browser();

    $this->browserDriver->start('https://192.168.3.69');
}
```

The thing that puzzles me is that the error indicates that the `StandardTestSuiteLoader` could not find the `Browser` class rather than in the test class where the class is instantiated.

Does anyone have some ideas why the auxillary class cannot be found?

Comment: Do you include (or rather 'require') `Browser.php`?

Comment: Can you share the autoloading configuration of your `composer.json`?

Comment: The browser class is included as

    require_once __DIR__ . "/webdriver/Browser.php";

Comment: I don't have an autoloading configuration in composer.json. Should I?

Comment: Are you using any namespaces for any of these classes?

Comment: Can you share the code of `HomePage.php`?

Comment: I have refactored alot of the code. So the code to HomePage.php no longer is how it was when the question was first phrased. I have reverted to doing it the 'wrong' way. My goal was to abstract the browser and driver portions in separate classes but it appears that having those classes derived from PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase (in order to get the functionality of the extension) causes this problem. But this goal is put on the side-line right now until I figure out how to just include the selenium and browser stuff apart from the PHP test extension.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like selenium in the PHPUnit library is cannot be bundled as a framework. I have since moved on to the selenium libraries for C# and Java.